# Why is Google Compute Engine's compute-optimized CPU slower than a laptop on number crunching in Python

Tags: python, performance, google-cloud-platform, python-multiprocessing

I am running the following code both on my Precision 5520 laptop and on Google Compute Engine's c2-standard-4:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def foo():
    before = time.time()
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, 100000000):
        sum += i
    print(time.time() - before, sum)

for i in range(mp.cpu_count()):
    mp.Process(target=foo).start()
```

In both cases, `mp.cpu_count()` is 4. However, unexpectedly to me, each computation on the laptop takes 5.2 seconds, while it takes 8.6 seconds on GCE.

The laptop runs Xeon E3-1505M v6 @ 3GHz. It is a strong CPU, but I would expect that a laptop CPU cannot compare with a CPU at a Google HPC server (e.g. because of heat limitations).

Python version on the laptop is 3.8.5. GCE has Python version 3.9.2.

Why could that be the case?

**Update** Following the reply by @John Hanley, I changed the configuration at Google Cloud Platform, so it uses only one vCPU per core and the time is now 4 seconds instead of 8.6. This is astonishing, as it seems to undermine the whole idea of using hyper-threads...

Comment: I find the 5.2 second number suspicious.  My Intel Xeon Silver 4110 is a better CPU than the i7-7700 in your laptop, and it takes 6.4 seconds for the first result (of 16).  (For safer mp use, you should have the last two lines in an `if __name__ == '__main__':`, by the way.)

Comment: Is the Python version the same (there are substantial jumps across even minor versions)? What's your laptop CPU (some Precisions feature rather powerful Xeons)? Is cache equally warm in both cases (it would not be fair to compare first run to the third)? Is the background workload equal in these tests (is GCE instance running any services)?

Comment: @Marat It's only sum, so I believe that cache is irrelevant.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning [Memory deduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_same-page_merging)

Comment: @TimRoberts I added CPU info to the question.

Comment: @Marat I still don't see why warming up cache would matter for this example...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning First run will create memory pages with certain content. Pages are not freed immediately (implementation dependent, I don't know how it is implemented in GCE), so subsequent runs will likely reuse them. If this, even theoretically, might influence execution speed, that it's probably a good idea to control for this factor.

Comment: @Marat How long can creating one memory page take?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your laptop, each CPU core is two Hyper-Threads.

In the cloud, one virtualized CPU (vCPU) is one Hyper-Thread.

Your laptop, given the same motherboard, clock speed, memory, etc has two times the equivalent CPU power per CPU. When you configure a VCPU in the cloud you are configuring one-half of a physical CPU core.

> On Compute Engine, each virtual CPU (vCPU) is implemented as a single
> hardware multithread on one of the available CPU processors. On Intel
> Xeon processors, Intel Hyper-Threading Technology supports multiple
> app threads running on each physical processor core. You configure
> your Compute Engine VM instances with one or more of these
> multithreads as vCPUs. The specific size and shape of your VM instance
> determines the number of its vCPUs.

[Google Cloud CPU Platforms](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms)

Comment: I'm wondering why you think this explains his results.  Having two hyperthreads does not double the SPEED of a given CPU.  It lets him run more processes, but it does not change the speed of a single process in any way.

Comment: @TimRoberts - because a system running one core with two hyper-threads and not sharing the core with two simultaneous threads will be faster than the CPU in the cloud with two threads running on the same core. VM A  and VM B can be sharing the same physical core reducing the performance of each vCPU. If two hyper-threads are consuming more than 50% each, you do not get more than 100% of a single core.

Comment: I think I have hyperthreading disabled, as the Task Manager in Windows shows that there are four logical processors...

Comment: @TimRoberts - to rewrite my last comment. On his laptop, a single thread can consume up to 100% of a single core. In the cloud, a single thread can consume up to 50% of a single core on average.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Disabling Hyper-Threading would not decrease the performance of a single CPU-bound thread. On Windows start Task Manager. Go to the **Performance** tab. Under the graphic look for two items; **Cores** and **Logical Processors**. If you have disabled Hyper-Threading, review why you want it disabled.

Comment: @JohnHanley -- I grant that two processes running on two hyperthreads of a single core get less performance than two processes running on two separate cores, but (A) the penalty is nowhere NEAR 50%, otherwise hyperthreads would be a stupid idea, and (B) those other hyperthreads are probably busy doing something else.

Comment: @TimRoberts - that logic does not apply to virtualization where CPU usage can be throttled/managed by the HyperVisor. That is one reason you see **burst** modes in the cloud where a vCPU can exceed 100% which is actually only 50% of a CPU core. The cloud provider is giving one vCPU more resources than another vCPU for a period of time.

Comment: See the update at the bottom of the question...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - what did you change?

Comment: vCPUs to core ratio - 1 vCPU per core

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - where did you change that?

Comment: In the web interface Edit->Details->Machine Configuration